# Why does SBT not detect main class in Java? (No main class detected)

Tags: java, sbt

SBT will complile, but not run this very simple project.  Why not?

```
mackler@localhost:~/tmp/javahello$ sbt --version                                                                       
sbt launcher version 0.12.1                                                                                            
mackler@localhost:~/tmp/javahello$ find .                                                                              
.                                                                                                                      
./src                                                                                                                  
./src/main                                                                                                             
./src/main/java                                                                                                        
./src/main/java/learn                                                                                                  
./src/main/java/learn/HelloWorld.java                                                                                  
mackler@localhost:~/tmp/javahello$ cat src/main/java/learn/HelloWorld.java                                             
package learn;                                                                                                         

class HelloWorld {                                                                                                     
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                           
        System.out.println("Hello, world");                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                      
mackler@localhost:~/tmp/learn/javahello$ sbt run                                                                       
[info] Set current project to default-1004d5 (in build file:/home/mackler/tmp/javahello/)                              
[info] Updating {file:/home/mackler/tmp/javahello/}default-1004d5...                                                   
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...                                                                
[info] Done updating.                                                                                                  
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /home/mackler/tmp/javahello/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...                            
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.                                                                    
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)                                                                          
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.                                              
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.                                                                          
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 22, 2013 4:14:21 PM                                                             
mackler@localhost:~/tmp/javahello$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration of the class needs to be public, otherwise sbt (and java) can't see it:

```
package learn;                                                                                                         

public class HelloWorld {                      // added public here
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                           
        System.out.println("Hello, world");                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                  
}
```

This works.

```
> run
[info] Running learn.HelloWorld
Hello, world
```

EDIT: In fact, the class doesn't need to be public for java to work, this is a bug in sbt, as Mark points out.

Comment: Fascinating; thank you.  I copied that right out of the first section of Gosling's book.  It works as originally posted using `javac` and `java` but I guess he should update the book to reflect SBT.

Comment: If `java` accepts it but `sbt` does not, it is a bug in sbt.  Please open an issue.

Comment: That is weird. I assumed that it would not work in java as well, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across similar problem.

It was compiling and No main class detected at runtime.

The problem was that I used compiler from java 1.6 and java 1.7 as runtime, check versions of compiler and runtime: 
javac -version 
and 
java -version
Now point to the same version and its ok.

Good luck!

Comment: Similar but different.  The problem I observed [reportedly has been fixed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/883), though I have not confirmed that myself.